# Pass data to parent view--communication between views

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have created a view which has a `GridView` and a `Button`. I call it `a parent view`. At the beginning, the `ItemsSource` collection of `GridView` is empty. Now I click the button to pop up a modal/popup view I call it as a `Child view`.

In the child view there are a couple buttons. One of them is to create new record for the parent view.

For example, if I click it, a new row data is generated.

Now my question is how to send the data just created back to the parent view so that the `GridView` in the parent view can be refreshed?

Comment: Why down voted it? I haven't used `IEventAggregator`  before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IEventAggregator` service to communicate between the two `views` Create an event, subscribe to it in the parent view or the parent view `ViewModel`, and publish it in the child view or the child view `ViewModel`. This way, there is no explicit dependency between the two views.
Your record model class:

```
public class RecordModel
{
    //Some Properties
}
```

Declare the event:

```
public class RecordAdded : PubSubEvent<RecordModel>
{

}
```

In the parent view / viewModel:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<RecordAdded>().Subscribe(OnRecordAdded);
private void OnRecordAdded(RecordModel e)
{

}
```

In your child view / viewmodel:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<RecordAdded>().Publish(new RecordModel
{
    //The popup data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view models will be doing all the work, I suppose. If so, you have a lot of options for communication between them, the most obvious is through `IEventAggregator`. Alternatively, create a service as data source for the parent view, and give it an iterface to the child view that exposes the `CreateItem` functionality... for the service to notify the parent view of the new item, you can go for `ObservableCollection`, `INotifyPropertyChanged`, `IEventAggregator` or simple .Net events, just to name a few examples.

`IEventAggregator` example:

```
internal class ChildViewModel
{
    public ChildViewModel( IEventAggregator eventAggregator )
    {
        CreateItemCommand = new DelegateCommand( () => eventAggregator.GetEvent<ItemCreatedEvent>().Publish( new Item() ) );
    }
}

internal class ParentViewModel
{
    public ParentViewModel( IEventAggregator eventAggregator )
    {
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<ItemCreatedEvent>().Subscribe( x => UpdateData( x ) );
    }
}
```